# Why CentOS lost its network interface?

Tags: centos, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 VPS which I had multiple sites on its Apache, and these days I faced a strange problem, CentOS lost its interface many times a day! and I should restart the interface to recover this situation! I've take a snapshot from Web console interface of my VPS, any idea? thanks in advance[image: CentOS 7 lost interface!]

`grep dhclient /var/log/messages`  ferquently give me this error (also I have `BOOTPROTO="dhcp"` in my config file) :

`Apr 30 15:12:56 vultr dhclient[8962]: dhclient.c:2676: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Apr 30 15:13:15 vultr dhclient[8962]: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 169.254.169.254 port 67 (xid=0x5f5ca74d)
Apr 30 15:13:15 vultr dhclient[8962]: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Apr 30 15:13:15 vultr dhclient[8962]: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.`

Comment: Is that a DHCP address? Could the lease be running out and failing to renew?

Comment: Yes that is DHCP address, if it is the case you are talking about is my CentOS responsible for this problem or my VPS provider? also my IP is always the same

Comment: Does the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file have a `BOOTPROTO=dhcp` line in it? What does `grep dhclient /var/log/messages` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I work for the host in this case)

There was an issue with the DHCP server that was causing some instances to lose their IP address on DHCP lease renewal.  Specifically, the DHCP server would intermittently respond with a NAK, which would cause the server to lose it's IP address.  Oddly, CentOS 7 doesn't seem to handle this nicely (nice behavior would be trying to obtain a new lease, rather then breaking connectivity until the interface was restarted).

You should no longer see issues with this.